# Include/Write Section from Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to include a section defined in partial file? If so, how?

I have a partial called `MetaTags.cshtml` that contains a section `MetaTags`. I use a section because I want views to be able to override this with custom tags when needed - for example; for a blog post page the user can add custom facebook metatags. The section is in a partial to keep the `_Layout.cshtml` more manageable and for code separation.

The following usage doesn't work: `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("MetaTags", required: true)

    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    ...
</head>
```

Comment: No its not possible - sections are not supported in partial views.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, any idea how I could have a default `MetaTags` content that can be overridden if needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the section in View (not partial view), it should work.

There is no way of using section in partial, but you can use other way such as ViewBag or Custom Html helper to achieve this.

Below is a sample of ViewBag method:

in your _Layout

```
     @Html.Partial("partial",  new ViewDataDictionary { {"vb", ViewBag}})

    @if (ViewBag.MetaInfo != null)
    {
        var metaDict = ViewBag.MetaInfo as IDictionary<string, string>;

        if(metaDict != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in metaDict)
            {
                <meta name="@item.Key" content="@item.Value" />
            }
        }
    }
</head>
```

then in partial view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.LayoutPageVB = ((dynamic)ViewData["vb"]);
    var metaDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    metaDict.Add("title", "c");
    ViewBag.LayoutPageVB.MetaInfo = metaDict;
}
```

you will get meta tag title being `c`

**personally, I think this is not a good approach, and it is not the response of partial to update layout, but it is one way of achieving what you need.**